# prove that there is no non zero solution to $a^3+b^3=c^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, arithmetic

Prove that there do not exist three consecutive positive integers a, b, c such that $a^3+b^3=c^3$. 
How do we proof this using contradiction?

Comment: You might write those integers as $n, n+1, n+2$.

Comment: Overkill method: use the special case of Fermat's Last Theorem with power 3 (I think this special case was proved already by Euler).

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://goo.gl/OWv9nr) to format your posts.

Answer (score 3):

Write $\;a=n-1\,,\,\,b=n\,,\,\,c=n+1\;$ , so you want to know whether$

$$(n-1)^3+n^3=(n+1)^3\iff2n^3-3n^2+3n-1=n^3+3n^2+3n+1\iff$$

$$n^3-6n^2+6n-2=0$$

and now use the rational root of integer polynomial theorem.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation mod $4$.

Answer (score 1):

if the order of the integers is $a \lt b \lt c$ then $a$ and $c$ must be odd and $b$ even. so for some $n$
$$
8n^3 -24n^2 -2 =0
$$
now apply @Robert's hint